# How to store Bert embeddings in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, embedding, bert-language-model

I want to use Cassandra as feature store to store precomputed Bert embedding,
Each row would consist of roughly 800 integers (ex. `-0.18294132`) Should I store all 800 in one large string column or 800 separate columns?

Simple read pattern, On read we would want to read every value in a row. Not sure which would be better for serialization speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having everything as a separate column will be quite inefficient - each value will have its own metadata (writetime, for example) that will add significant overhead (at least 8 bytes per every value).  Storing data as string will be also not very efficient, and will add the complexity on the application side.

I would suggest to store data as [fronzen list](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/refCollectionType.html) of integers/longs or doubles/floats, depending on your requirements.  Something like:

```
create table ks.bert(
  rowid int primary key,
  data frozen<list<int>>
);
```

In this case, the whole list will be effectively serialized as binary blob, occupying just one cell.

Comment: just one note - it will work well if you retrieve individual rows, but if you're doing the loading of the whole model, then it could be inefficient as Cassandra isn't much optimized for the whole table scans.  In this case maybe look to other formats/solutions, like, Parquet or Delta Lake, etc.  Of course it all depends on the access patterns & latency requirements

Comment: Yeah, I had that worry as well, reading from multiple partitions is not ideal. But I think I will only be reading at most a few hundred at a time, which should work?

Comment: yes, it will work - just use async API and run all requests in parallel, so they will be handled independently... Another way is to have partition consisting of multiple rows, if you can group them together some way